# При заполнение формы открыть в новой вкладке страницу?

Tags: javascript

есть форма с отправкой данных на е-майл. При заполнение и отправке надо что бы пользователю открывался файл который находится по адресу /lessons/l1.pdf

сделал что бы после отправки в новом окне открывалась страница

```
window.open('static/lessons/survey.pdf');
```

Но chrom'e блокирует. Как лучше здесь поступить?

Comment: Ну так и должно быть, вам надо "заставить" пользователя сделать действие(click) после можете открыть новый таб

Answer (score 0):

На локалхосте в хроме у меня такой код работает:

```
<form onsubmit="window.open('http://google.com');">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form target="_blank">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]